# Unable to delete folder using Delete activity in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a folder structure as below in a blob storage container

```
Main
    RunID
         Folder1
                Folder 2
                         data.csv
```

I have created a 'delete activity' in the data factory to discard the folder "Main"

[image: location specified in the data source :]

However, I keep getting an error of Failed to execute delete activity with data source 'AzureBlobStorage' and error 'The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict. The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.'.

Please suggest a solution to overcome this issue.

Thank you

Comment: I tried running this on my subscription and the delete worked as expected. Can you cut paste the ADF activity JSON source code so we can check the ADF settings. I can only suspect the error may be due to some setting on the Blob/container itself. You can see a list of possible reasons for the 409 error here [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-error-codes). Examples are an active immutable access policy on the container.

Comment: @AnupamChand Kindly find the code in the below post .

Comment: @AnupamChand i tried the same thing with a different subscription where i am the owner of the container , the same workflow works fine .

Answer (score 0):

If I try to delete the data.csv file through the pipeline it works but doesn't work when I try to delete the folder.
The JSON source code for the ADF pipeline.
I have the  contributor, storage blob data contributor, and storage account, contributor access

```
{
"name": "Delete files older than 30 days",
"properties": {
    "description": "Please input a folder path as the parameter for this pipeline, and the pipeline will delete files which were last modified more than 30 days ago under the particular folder path.",
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "DeleteFiles",
            "description": "Connect to your storage account to save the log file.",
            "type": "Delete",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "BinaryDatasetForDeleteActivity",
                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                    "parameters": {
                        "FolderPath": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.SourceFolder",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        },
                        "Directory": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.SourceDirectory",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "logStorageSettings": {
                    "linkedServiceName": {
                        "referenceName": "linkedService1",
                        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                    },
                    "path": {
                        "value": "@pipeline().parameters.LoggingPath",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                },
                "enableLogging": true,
                "storeSettings": {
                    "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                    "recursive": true,
                    "wildcardFileName": "*"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "SourceFolder": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "ildatalakefs /"
        },
        "SourceDirectory": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Client1 / Staging / 3f1890d4-dd35-4130-baad-a1d39972ac99 / Landing/"
        },
        "LoggingPath": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "loggingfolder/subfolder"
        }
    },
    "annotations": [],
    "lastPublishTime": "2021-04-26T22:54:14Z"
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
```

}

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I tried the repro the scenario and I failed , but just to be sure that I let others know that the solution does need the implementation of paramterized dataset , which I am sure you are doing .

Do you know as to how many blobs are there in folder which you are trying to delete ? I think the 409 is coming from the delete API for storage .
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-error-codes

[image]

As a test can you please point the folder where you have only few blobs? Since the foldername is a paramter this is should be easy to test . I am sure with few files your pipeline will work just fine .